# windows batch wmic diskdrive get size where media type = Fixed hard disk media

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I need to get the size of locally installed hard disk/disks size via windows batch file,  please help

```
for /f ? %%f in ('wmic diskdrive where (MediaType='Fixed hard disk media') get size /value') do echo "%%f"
```

Comment: What's with the question mark?

Comment: I m new to scripting, help is needed to create a batch file for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC LogicalDisk Where (DriveType='3') Get DeviceID, Size"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ("%%A") Do Echo(%%B - %%C
Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 1):

As LogicalDisk will return only the partition size and with modern drives the capacity will exceed the 32bit signed integer math of cmd.exe's set /A command, I suggest using a PowerShell script to get some data:

```
$Drives=0 ; $TotalSize=0
get-physicaldisk | 
  ForEach {$_;$Drives+=1;$TotalSize+=$_.Size}|
    Format-Table -auto DeviceID,Size,BusType,MediaType,model,serialnumber
"Drives       TotalSize"
"------- --------------"
"{0,-6} {1,15}" -f $Drives,$TotalSize
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SO_42525626.ps1

DeviceID          Size BusType MediaType   model                      serialnumber
--------          ---- ------- ---------   -----                      ------------
1         256060514304 SATA    SSD         Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
0        2000398934016 SATA    HDD         ST2000DL003-9VT166         yyyyyyyy
3        1000204886016 USB     Unspecified 2105                       zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz


Drives       TotalSize
------- --------------
3        3256664334336
```

Comment: thanks but em not much familiar with PowerShell scripting.